# How to get the line number from the call site using __LINE__ or some other method?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, macros, preprocessor, line-numbers

Consider this short program that I wrote:

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    template<bool Debug = false>
    constexpr int add(const int& a, const int& b) { 
        if (Debug)
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " called on line " << __LINE__ << '\n';
        return (a + b);
    }
    
    int main() {
        std::cout << add(3, 7) << '\n';
        std::cout << add<true>(5, 9) << '\n';
        return 0;
    }
```

It works just fine, and it gives the proper output:

```
10
add called on line 6
14
```

However, I'd like for the line number that is printed to be the line at the call site of the program which in this program should be line 12.

So how can I use `__LINE__` or some other method to give me the line number from where the function was invoked?

The desired output would be:

```
10
add called on line 12
14
```

I would like for it to be generated from the function itself if possible.

---

***-EDIT-***

As a note to the reader, I'm open to any and all options but I am limited to C++17 for my current build environment and I'm using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call it like this instead:

```cpp
template<bool Debug = false>
constexpr int add(const int& a, const int& b, int loc = __LINE__) { 
    if (Debug)
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " called on line " << loc << '\n';
    return (a + b);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << add(3, 7) << '\n';
    std::cout << add<true>(5, 9, __LINE__) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10
add called on line 14
14
```

Furthermore, You can define a macro to skip the third argument:

```
#define add_Debug(a, b) add<true>(a,b,__LINE__)
```

---

#### C++ 20 and beyond

With C++20, we are getting [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) which contains information about line number, function, file name. If your compiler supports it, you can use that. Example (tested with g++ 9.3.0). You will not need macros anymore:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/source_location>

using source_location = std::experimental::source_location;

template<bool Debug = false>
constexpr int add(const int& a, const int& b, source_location l = source_location::current()) { 
    if (Debug)
          // this will print 'main' as function name
          //std::cout << l.function_name() << " called on line " << l.line() << //'\n';
        std::cout << source_location::current().function_name() << " called on line " << l.line() << '\n';


    return (a + b);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << add(3, 7) << '\n';
    std::cout << add<true>(5, 9) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10
add<true> called on line 16
14
```

With `source_location` you don't have to use macros anymore. It will correctly print the line

Comment: Not exactly what I was asking for. The function call itself happens at line 12 in the code within the main function. That's the line number that I'm after.

Comment: I am adding more, bear with me :)

Comment: This should work... however, having to add that into every function... ehh

Comment: It's for debug - unit testing and writing to log files though...

Comment: I hear that C++20 has a new proposed feature... can't wait to be able to start using it!

Comment: Hmm maybe add it into the `template arguments` instead of the function itself...

Comment: I tried using it as a template argument, setting the template argument as a default to `__LINE__` works, however, when I try to use `__LINE__` as the second parameter when instantiating the template, it does fail to compile because the `__LINE__` macro isn't considered a compile-time constant expression.

Comment: It does work, but the line information you will get will be incorrect unless you explicitly pass `__LINE__` like add<true, __LINE__>(5, 9).
With source_location, this is not an issue. You can just use it as a function parameter and it will print information of line which called the function

Comment: I tried doing that `add<true,__LINE__>(5,9)` but it was failing to compile for Visual Studio...

Comment: It's compiling for all compilers for me, see: https://godbolt.org/z/T91s5s

Comment: Okay, I changed Compiler Explorer's settings to match my environment: x64 MSVC 19.24 and changed it to c++17. It compiled there fine. In Visual Studio 2017 when I compile it in Debug mode it is generating: `C2672` and `C2975` compile errors. However, when I switch to release mode, it compiles, builds, runs, and produces the correct output... Curious, I wonder if this is a Visual Studio Bug...

Comment: Could be a bug in MSVC. Cause there are no C++17 only features in that template function.

Comment: I just asked another question in regards to it being a potential bug! https://stackoverflow.com/q/62870536/1757805 However, I got a downvote from it already...

Answer (score 2):

If you could compile your code on Linux using some recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (in July 2020, that means [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/)), you might compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -g -O -Wall` then use Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) (like we do in [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/)) since that library parses [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information.

You might either port that library to your operating system and debug info format, or find some equivalent.

Today, a cruder possibility could be to wrap some functions with macros. For example, instead of calling `foo()` with some `void foo(void);` you would have

```
extern void foo_at(const char*fileno, int lineno);
#define foo() foo_at(__FILE__,__LINE__);
```

Indeed, C++20 should add [feature tests](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) and [`source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location) but you might need to wait a few months for a compiler supporting it. Consider compiling a recent GCC from its source code. AFAIK [MinGW 64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) runs on Windows (so ask permission to use it).

Comment: Yeah, but that's kind of going backward towards C programming, I'm trying to push the limits of C++ and move forward!